# using ConnectedComponentsLabeling to get the connected items

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge, blobs

Is there a way to get the connected objects using connected component labeling in aforge.net? I know how to label the objects but is there a way that i could iterate through each an every connected component in a particular image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS i have found out you can sort the objects in a particular order and then iterate through them. this was already provided in the documentation